# html-JavaScript- when switching to next div only displays for a split second then disappears

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my function. I want to switch from one div to another. I am getting this to happen but only for a quick second then it returns back to the first div.

```
function NextDiv()
    {
        var div = document.querySelectorAll("#div0>div");
        for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++)
        {
            if (div[i].style.display != "none")
            {
                div[i].style.display = "none";
                if (i == div.length - 1)
                {
                    div[0].style.display = "block";
                }
                else
                {
                    div[i + 1].style.display = "block";
                }
                return false;
            }
        }      
    }
```

here is a testable fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnumtc35/5/

Comment: would you be so kind to offer some live testable code? use the `<>` button

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pnumtc35/5/ @Pilan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the line where you do `div[i+1]` the new div gets shown. but on the next iteration of your `for-loop` it get immediately hidden again. Thats why i added a `break` to stop the loop.

```js
function NextDiv()
        {
            console.log('click');
            var div = document.querySelectorAll("#div0>div");
            for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++)
            {
                if (div[i].style.display != "none")
                {
                    div[i].style.display = "none";
                    if (i == div.length - 1)
                    {
                        div[0].style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        div[i + 1].style.display = "block";
                        break; // ADDED
                    }
                    
                }
            }      
        }
```

```html
 <div id="div0">
    <div class="column" id="div1" >
        <h2>Customer Information </h2>
        <button runat="server" id="nextbutton" onclick="NextDiv()" >Next </button>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="div2" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Payment Information</h2>
        <button runat="server" id="Button1" onclick="NextDiv()">Next </button>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="div3" style="display: none;">
        <h2>Shipment Information</h2>
        <Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="SaveInfo"/>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: I've have tried this too. It still does the same thing. I am using telerik textboxes. Could this be causing an issue?

Comment: I have tried putting break and return false that is it. https://jsfiddle.net/pnumtc35/26/

Comment: Then take a look WHERE the break is :)